# почему у меня при уменьшении экрана форма выходит за блок?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    <div class="wrapp-input row form-group">
                        <label for="CompanyName" class="col-sm-4 control-label" >Company Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="name" class="form-control" id="CompanyName">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrapp-input row form-group">
                        <label for="FirstName" class="col-sm-4 control-label" >First Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="name" class="form-control" id="FirstName">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrapp-input row form-group">
                        <label for="LastName" class="col-sm-4 control-label" >Last Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="name" class="form-control" id="LastName">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrapp-input row form-group">
                        <label for="Role" class="col-sm-4 control-label" >Role</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="name" class="form-control" id="Role">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrapp-textarea form-group row">
                        <label for="TellUs" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Tell us abot<br> your needs</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <textarea type="name" rows="6" class="form-control" id="TellUs"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="wrapp-textarea form-group row">
                        <label for="HowDid" class="col-sm-4 control-label">How did your hear<br>about us</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <textarea type="name" rows="6" class="form-control" id="HowDid"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

CSS

```
.form-horizontal .control-label{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: left;
    padding-top: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input{
    float: right;
}

div.active:hover{
    background-color: #558CFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 500px;
}

.wrapp-input{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 8px;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.wrapp-textarea{
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 8px;
    height: 150px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.wrapp-input:hover{
    background-color: #558CFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.form-control{
    margin-top: -2px;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вероятно, у вас разрешение меньше, чем прописано для класса `col-sm-*`

Answer (score 2):

На уменьшенном размере экрана input имеет ширину 100% и опускается вниз. При этом, для родительского блока задана статическая высота 50px и он не вмещается там.

```
.wrapp-input {
    height: 50px;
}
```